# Can I create read-only properties in Java?

Tags: java

I'm creating a custom array class, and it has an `int` property `size`.

This property is modified automatically if you do something like `add()` or `remove()`. I want to let the user read this property like `myArray.size`. However, making it `public` allows the user to change it, which doesn't make much sense for my class, and could break it.

I could of course make it `private` and create a getter method `size()` and all's good. I don't have a problem with that, but still, is there a way to make a read-only property in Java?

Looking around the web, I found this:

- http://binkley.blogspot.com/2005/01/read-only-properties-in-java.html

Their solution goes like

```
public final String title;
```

Which is tecnically valid, but that of course doesn't work for my array, since my property is not constant.

Comment: In Short: No, you can't.

Comment: What's the problem with the getter? That is _the_ way to do it in Java.

Comment: Why not use a getSize() method instead? "Properties" aren't in Java's characteristics, why do you try to make Java look like C#?

Comment: @MattBall: I don't have a problem with the getter, as mentioned in the question. I was just curious.

Comment: Only `final` fields (not "properties") prevent reassignment in Java. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're describing is not possible in Java.

Comment: Getter allows to change an object by its reference.

Comment: By "getter" I was referring to OP's statement: "I could of course make it private and create a getter method `size()`." I assume `size()` would return an int, which would be immutable. Updated my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is for the user to be able to get the object's size but not be able to write to it.  In this case, you keep the value of `size` as `private`.  You are absolutely right that making size `public` will allow a user to break your objects by setting the value of `size` to something that it is not!

What you want is a `getSize()` method that is `public` and `return` ' s the value of `size`.  The user can call the method to read the value, but has no way of actually writing to the value of `size`.

If you really want to learn about making part or all of your data structure immutable, you could check here:

Immutable Objects
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

Answer (score 2):

Make use of getters/setters. Or rather, just getters without the setters in your case.

Look for an example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

So make the property private, and create a public method to 'get' its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a read only array, you can use ImmutableList : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/javatools/util/ImmutableList.html

Comment: Interesting, I only knew the Guava implementations for immutable data structures. The `oracle.javatools.util.ImmutableList` is not part of the official standard, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure actually, sorry

Answer (score 0):

A simple getter is the natural approach, as [Java lacks support for properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28programming%29#Support_in_languages).
So, a getter is what the typical Java programmer would expect.

Even if it is possible to use public fields, as in your `public final String title` example, I would not recommend it. For example, it is annoying when you give your code to someone else who wants to write unit tests for it and uses mocking frameworks.

Public fields should generally be reserved for (static) constants.